# No way to get the "fat fonts" on Fedora 30 or better rendering as Slackware 14.2?

Tags: fonts

Look this very good rendering on Slackware 14.2
in my opinion is near perfect.

[image]

Now look the same page on Fedora 30

[image]

In my opinion the fonts on Fedora are too small and difficult to read, I prefer the fat fonts of Slackware 14.2.
Is possible to get the same rendering?
On Fedora I use the same settings of Slackware

```
Fonts: Deja Vu sans 10
DPI: 96
Hinting: slight
```

Of course Firefox use the same settings too 
Sans Serif 16

On /etc/profile.d/freetype.sh I use this settings on Fedora

```
export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES=truetype:interpreter-version=35
```

And /etc/X11/Xresources is this on Fedora

```
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.autohint: false
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.lcdfilter: lcddefault
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
```

On Slackware is missing,so I cannot paste.

Any suggestion to avoid headache and eyes burning and get the same rendering of Slackware 14.2?
I have noticed the same problem on Slackware current
I use the Freetype 35 because otherwise fonts are even more small and unreadable.

Comment: If you are referring to the difference in font families used for body text on the page, it comes down to different fontconfig rules and different fonts installed on both systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply backup the /etc/fonts in Fedora

```
cp -a /etc/fonts/conf.d /etc/fonts/conf.d.old
```

Then I have copied the configuration from Slackware

```
rsync -avP slack:/etc/fonts/conf.d/ fedora:/etc/fonts/conf.d
rsync -avP slack:/etc/fonts/conf.avail/ fedora:/etc/fonts/conf.avail
```

Now finally I get the good fat fonts

[image]

Better result using this variable

```
vim /etc/profile.d/freetype.sh

export FREETYPE_PROPERTIES=truetype:interpreter-version=35
```

Probably is not necessary but this patch to freetype give (personal opinion) a better rendering

```
--- include/freetype/config/ftoption.h    2019-07-14 15:15:05.380268643 +0200
+++ include/freetype/config/ftoption.h    2019-07-14 15:15:10.254336367 +0200
@@ -658,7 +658,7 @@
   /* [1] https://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/truetypecleartype.aspx */
   /*                                                                       */
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  1         */
-#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  2
+#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  1
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  ( 1 | 2 ) */


--- devel/ftoption.h    2019-07-14 15:16:30.870456502 +0200
+++ devel/ftoption.h    2019-07-14 15:17:05.095932053 +0200
@@ -631,7 +631,7 @@
   /*                                                                       */
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  1     */
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  2     */
-#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING     ( 1 | 2 )
+#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING     1 


   /*************************************************************************/

--- include/freetype/config/ftoption.h.enable-spr    2019-07-14 15:28:38.516824794 +0200
+++ include/freetype/config/ftoption.h.enable-spr    2019-07-14 15:28:31.382970434 +0200
@@ -658,7 +658,7 @@
   /* [1] https://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/truetypecleartype.aspx */
   /*                                                                       */
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  1         */
-#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  2
+#define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  1
 /* #define TT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_HINTING  ( 1 | 2 ) */
```